# No such element for an element inside of a dialog

Tags: javascript, java, dialog, nosuchelementexception

When I try to click an element hosted inside of a dialog is returning NoSuch element exeption

[error returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc3KS.png)

I've tried using active element and also switch to default content but no success.
This portion of code has no iframes in the middle so a line that switchto an iframe is not needed

Here is the code:

```
public void editarDatosContacto(String contacto, String canal){
        openEditarContacto(botonAgregarCel());
        waitDefaultTime();
        getDriver().switchTo().parentFrame();
        getDriver().switchTo().parentFrame();
        WebDriverWait block = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(),10);
        block.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"midialogBpf01\"]/div/object")));
        WebElement modal = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"midialogBpf01\"]/div/object"));
        WebElement item;
        item = modal.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row']/div/div/div[1]/div/div//a[@data-toggle='modal']"));
        item.click();
        Select selectDato = new Select(selectTipo());
        selectDato.selectByVisibleText(contacto);

}
```

The line that is not finding the element is this:

```
item = modal.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row']/div/div/div[1]/div/div//a[@data-toggle='modal']"));
```

And this is the application
[html code to find the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duoLm.png)

The app is only accessed through a vpn so I can't share it.

Comment: I don't think this is related to the `dynamics-crm` tag. You should probably retag your question to get better results

Answer (score 1):

Solution find!

I had to switch to modal first like this

```
WebElement modal = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"midialogBpf01\"]/div/object"));
WebElement item;
driver.switchTo.frame(modal);
item = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row']/div/div/div[1]/div/div//a[@data-toggle='modal']"));
item.click();
```

So that was the fix.

I hope this help someone with same issue.

Thanks